# Error - system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I copied the "win_flex_bison_2.5.5" to the project .. 
Build customization : added "win_flex_bison_custom_build.targets"
Made a file with extension (.L)
And the local windows debugger sent an alert 
"Unable to start program
D:\project\test.exe
The system cannot find the file specified"

And now idk why but 
And now i cant open an existing project
Or existing item .. i got an error 
"class not registered
Looking for object with CLSID
{C964830F-91A0-11D0-B14C-0000F8041356}"

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this, to allow file to go to output directory where your executable exists-

[image]

Comment: No executable file

Comment: what is test.exe then?

Comment: Idk .. VS2013 does not make test.exe .. the debug folder is empty